# ASP.net: How to make list of object sortable when bind to control such as gridview?

Tags: asp.net

I got a class let's call it Blah. I use ObjectDataSource to get the data from the database and the value is bind it to Blah's property for example, Column Foo is Blah.Foo in my class. I can bind ObjectDataSource with a list of Blah to a gridview but i can't make it sortable since the datasource is not datatable. Does anyone have link or tutorial on how to make object to be sortable for control like gridview.

thank

Jack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you could use the AllowSorting property of the gridview with SortExpression on your fields. Here is a [tutorial](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/e07f0f1a-4243-4050-8278-00d32b2e5121/aspnet--sorting-a-gridv.aspx)

Second, you could made a generic list of Blah and then call .Sort()

```
List<Blah> test = new List<Blah>;
test.AddRange(ObjectDataSource);
test.Sort();
```

[msdn information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6.aspx)

Third you could sort the gridview directly from an expression like

```
CustomersGridView.Sort(expression, direction);
```

[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sort.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the IComparable interfaces.  There may be other interfaces you need to implement, but they will all be in the same vein.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement Icomparable then pass the sort expression from the gridview to your custom sort method.

[Imar Spaanjaars](http://imar.spaanjaars.com/ViewContentList.aspx) has a nice tutorial and code examples of creating sortable business object collections that you can bind to asp.net controls

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try to sort your list using anonymous delegates:

```
List<YourObject> MyList = new List<YourObject>();

MyList.Sort(delegate(YourObject o1, YourObject o2)
{ return o1.SomeProperty.CompareTo(o2.SomeProperty);});
```

More about anonymous and delegate: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k(VS.80).aspx)